# Сравнить 2 массива отметив совпадение

Tags: php

Добрый день. Подскажите, мне нужно вывести один массив в виде checkbox, отметив те флажки, значения которых есть во втором массиве.

Есть массивы

```
$prop = Array
(
    [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => Пластиковые окна
            [1] => Натяжные потолки
            [2] => Установка дверей
            [3] => Укладка ламината
            [4] => Оклейка обоев
        )

)

$option_key = Array
(
    [0] => Натяжные потолки
    [1] => Оклейка обоев
    [2] => Пластиковые окна
);
```

Нужно вывести в виде флажков массив $prop, но при этом те значения, что есть в массиве $option_key отметить.

Пытался так, он мне все отмечает:

```
foreach ($prop as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $values) {
        print "<label><input";
        if (isset($prop[$k])) {
            print " checked "; 
        }
        print "type='checkbox' name='$k'> $values</label>";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как то так?

```
foreach($prop as $k => $p){
   $checked = in_array($p, $option_key) ? "checked" : "";

   echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='$k' $checked>$p</label>";
}
```

Comment: Стоп. А почему в 1 аргументе функции `in_array` - вы передаете массив в котором нужно делать поиск? Неправильно написано - нужно так: `in_array($p, $option_key)` - то есть, поменять местами.

Comment: @And потому что наизусть порядок следования аргументов всех функций я не помню (: хотел проверить, но отвлекся. поправил.

Comment: У меня выдает только один чекбокс с значением Array

Comment: @teran может я что-то неправильно делю, foreach один получается нужен?

Comment: @Batyabest значит у вас `$prop` имеет не такой вид, как вы написали, а что-то вроде `$prop = [ 0 => [ 'Пластиковые окна', '...', ... ]]`

Comment: @teran изначально $prop такой, как я исправил в вопросе, да моя ошибка. Получается его нужно пройтись foreach?

Comment: @Batyabest `foraech($prop['values'] as $v)...`

Comment: @teran да так и сделал, но он выводит все чекбоксы, но ни один не отмечен. вот код
foreach($prop['values'] as $k => $p){
   $checked = (in_array($p, $options_key)) ? "checked" : "";

   echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='$k' $ckecked>$p</label>";
}

Comment: @Batyabest `$ckecked` => `$checked`

Comment: это у меня опечатка была